# Akka Streams - define timeout for mapAsync

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am using Akka stream with an external service which its methods takes time.
I don't want this methods to block so I defined a flow which uses mapAsyncUnordered as follows:

`Flow.of(SomeClass.class).mapAsyncUnordered(numThreads, someService::someMethod);`

I want to define a timeout to the method running in the mapAsyncUnordered stage, so that if the method takes too much time, it won't fill the mapAsyncUnordered queue and prevent from others to pass.

The only option I saw is to define a different actor and use "ask" method of it,  but as described in the documentation, if we arrive to timeout, the whole stream will be terminated with failure and this is not good for me (although it can be recovered, since I can't lose data).
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/futures-interop.html

Is there another option?

Comment: There are two parts to add: 1. how to add a timeout to a CompletableFuture and 2. how to deal with errors (like timeouts) gracefully. For 1., see http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html for a few pointers of how to add a timeout to any future.

Comment: For ignoring errors, you could wrap both normal or exceptional results e.g. using `CompletableFuture.handle` to convert the result into an Optional value. Then you can add a `filter` combinator afterwards to remove the errorneous result and a map to unpack the successful results again. Another way to deal with 2. would be to set configure a `SupervisionStrategy.resume` which makes `mapAsyncUnordered` ignore errors in the first place. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies for more info.